# Fetch HTTPcallout API issues

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to do some POC on sObject tree. Below code run's fine . But i am just getting empty response {} in console.log. Not sure what i am doing wrong. Can you please help

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

const AccountData = {
  records: [
    {
      attributes: { type: "Account", referenceId: "ref1" },
      Name: "SampleAccount1"
    },
    {
      attributes: { type: "Account", referenceId: "ref2" },
      Name: "SampleAccount2"
    },
    {
      attributes: { type: "Account", referenceId: "ref3" },
      Name: "SampleAccount3"
    },
    {
      attributes: { type: "Account", referenceId: "ref4" },
      Name: "SampleAccount4"
    }
  ]
};

export default class Speechlwc extends LightningElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    fetch("../services/data/v48.0/composite/tree/Account/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",

      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        AccountData
      })
    }).then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Remote site settings already set to self? I believe you would still need Authorization to access the data.

Comment: I added my SFDC domain in Remote site settings. Then also its not working.  How to get authorization token for my own domain API?

Comment: You would need to access the SID in the cookie for your browser to leverage the bearer token already in place. Otherwise, you need to go through a separate login process within your code, which sounds like a horrible idea since it is in the front-end.

Comment: Could you please include a catch(error => console.log(error)) after then as the fetch promise might be failing...

Comment: After adding the catch block I a getting CORS error. So able to point the exact issue. but not able to resolve it. By googling for CORS issues I found some solution and implemented but its not helping me out  . I added like this in CORS setup    https://*.lightning.force.com   https://*.my.salesforce.com   https://chaarvim-dev-ed.lightning.force.com    https://chaarvim-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com    and my error is

Comment: Access to fetch at 'https://chaarvim-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/composite/tree/Account/' (redirected from 'https://chaarvim-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/services/data/v48.0/composite/tree/Account/') from origin 'https://chaarvim-dev-ed.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Is this URL is correct   `https://chaarvim-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/services/data/v48.0/composite/tree/Account/`   **or**    `https://chaarvim-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/services/data/v48.0/composite/tree/Account/`

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify({ AccountData })` causes an extra layer of object wrapping around the base object. I'll give a simple demo:

```
var x = { a: 5, b: 10 };
console.log(JSON.stringify(x)); // "{"a":5,"b":10}"
console.log(JSON.stringify({x})); // "{"x":{"a":5,"b":10}}"
```

Instead, just use:

```
JSON.stringify(AccountData)
```

Comment: Still I am getting empty response only.In chrome network console calls are going through without any issues.